# Maxima plot2d discrete with points

Tags: plot, gnuplot, maxima

I have a `samples` list with a collection of `(x,y)` coordinates pairs. I want to use `plot2d` to create a discrete plot from these points, not showing lines connecting each point.

This is my script:

```
plot2d(
  [discrete, samples],
  [style, [points, 1, 5, 1]],
  [legend, "Samples"],
  [gnuplot_term, "svg size 640,480"],
  [gnuplot_out_file, "graph_samples.svg"]
)$
```

But the result is a plot with connected points, as can be seen in the picture below. Despite the use of the `[style, [points, 1, 5, 1]]` option, the plot connects each point. The `style` definition seems to be ignored.

[image: Samples Plot]

Does anyone have a clue why is this happening? I know I could alternatively use `draw2d` but  I'd rather use `plot2d` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had a `points` matrix previously declared that was conflicting with the `style` definition. Changed its name and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

You can also [quote](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_8.html#IDX279) a symbol to prevent evaluation:

```
points: [1, 2, 3];
x: 42;
plot2d('x^2, ['x, 1, 2], ['style, 'points]);
```